# Create php fom select multiple taking values from a table bd

Tags: php, mysql

The table deportes has 2 columns with 4 rows:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM deportes';
$resul = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$deportes = array();    
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resul))
{
     $deportes[] = $fila;
}       
?>
```

The form with the select multiple options:

```
<select name="fan[]" multiple="multiple"> 
    <?php
        foreach ($deportes as $aficion)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$aficion['idD']."'";
            echo " >{$aficion['nombreDep']}  </option>\n";
        }
    ?>            
</select>
```

Get the values from the form

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fan']))
    {
    $sport = $_POST['fan'];
    }
?>
```

Now this

```
<?php $sport = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $sport); ?>
```

This way insert the values in another table

```
$idPersona = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);           
$sql = "INSERT INTO mec(id,idD) VALUES ('$idPersona','$sport') ";
```

And the result is i get the value "0" in the field idD from table mec

Comment: `$sport` is an array, not a string. Are you trying to insert `$sport` array data as comma separated values in the table?

Comment: No. The values for idD in deportes table are 1, 2, 3, 4. I would like to insert in the field idD in mec table these values one by one.

Comment: What's the purpose of this statement `$idPersona = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);` ? Do you have *any other* `INSERT` query apart from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `print_r` your `$_POST['fan']`, you will see that this is **array**. To get every value of array you should iterate over it, with `for` or `foreach`:

```
$idPersona = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);           
foreach ($_POST['fan'] as $sport) {
    echo $sport;   // you will see that now it is string
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mec(id,idD) VALUES ('$idPersona','$sport') ";
    // execute your query
}
```

And of course you **must** move to prepared statements to protect your code from sql-injection. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) will give you a start.

Comment: Thank u so much :)

Comment: Hello, again. Now i have other issue, i need to keep the values selected from the form:

    <select name="fan[]" multiple="multiple"> <!-- Aquí se llama a la     función verificarListaMultiple -->
                  <?php
     foreach ($deportes as $aficion)       
       {
        echo "<option  value='".$aficion['idD']."'";
        if (isset($fan)) verificarListaMultiple($aficion,$fan);
        echo " >{$aficion['nombreDep']}</option>\n";
       }
     ?>     
            </select>

Comment: Im trying to use a function like this:

` function verificarListaMultiple($array, $valor)
   {
        if (in_array($valor, $array))
       {
           echo 'selected = "selected"';
       }
   }

But, there is no way to keep the values. It would be so appreciated some kind of help. Thank you

Comment: Please, create __new__ question with your problem. Comments are not for this.