# How to keep the selected value from a multiple select form with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with this form. I need to keep the values selected and I don't find the way. The thread where I posted the first time: [Create php fom select multiple taking values from a table bd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041586/create-php-fom-select-multiple-taking-values-from-a-table-bd/42042009#42042009)

The form:

```
<select name="fan[]" multiple="multiple"> <!-- Aquí se llama a la función verificarListaMultiple -->
    <?php
        foreach ($deportes as $aficion) {
            echo "<option value='".$aficion['idD']."'";
            if (isset($fan)) {
                verificarListaMultiple($aficion,$fan);
            }
            echo " >{$aficion['nombreDep']}</option>\n";
        }
    ?>            
</select>
```

And the function I'm trying to use:

```
function verificarListaMultiple($array, $valor) {
    if (in_array($valor, $array)) {
        echo 'selected = "selected"';
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: change to: if (isset($fan)) verificarListaMultiple($fan, $aficion['idD']);

Comment: what is $fan? is it contain selected value?

Comment: print_r ($fan); exit();

Notice: Undefined variable: fan in C:\xampp\htdocs\amgPhp\index.php on line 59

Comment: if (isset($fan)) verificarListaMultiple($fan, $aficion['idD']); 

:( It doesn´t work

Comment: but that condition of if(isset($fan)) is neverrrr gonna meet. as fan is undefined, so option will never get selected.

Comment: you need to define $fan and give it a value.

Comment: i defined $depo = S_POST['fan'];

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i resolved on this way:

Form insert-data

```
<?php
    foreach ($deportes as $deporte)                         
        {
        echo "<option value='".$deporte['idD']."'";
        if (isset($depo)) verificarListaMultiple($depo, $deporte['idD']);
                            echo " >{$deporte['nombreDep']}</option>\n";
        }
?>
```

Then, the values are inserted in a table bd:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fan']))
    {
        $idPersona = mysqli_insert_id($conexion); 
        foreach ($depo as $sport) {
            $sport = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $sport);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO mec(id,idD) VALUES ('$idPersona','$sport') ";
            $resul = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
}
```

And finally i would like to edit the form edit_Data. The values showed, must be the values inserted in form edit_Data, and must be keep selected:

Form edit-data:

```
<?php
foreach ($deportes as $deporte)                           
    {
    echo "<option value='".$deporte['idD']."'";
    if (isset($depo)) verificarListaMultiple($depo, $deporte['idD']);
                        echo " >{$deporte['nombreDep']}</option>\n";
    }
?>
```